# SQL "Where exists" with multiple tables with aliases

Tags: sql, oracle

Example query:

```
Select id, id_dtm
From tableA 
Where exists (
 Select 1 
 From tableB b, tableC c, tableD d
 Where b.id = id
 And b.id_dtm = id_dtm
 And b.id = c.id
 And c.id = d.id);
```

The problem with the above query is that all 4 tables have columns named id and id_dtm. 
When i run it, i get an error saying that the columns ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

I could have fixed by using an alias in tableA but the problem is that the query is generated dynamically. The `where exists` portion is generated somewhere else and the bit before it is merged later so i cant use an alias as it is now.

Is there any way i can use id and id_dtm from tableA inside the `where exists` clause without using an alias for tableA?

Database is Oracle10G

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write the table name `tableA`:

```
Select id, id_dtm
From tableA 
Where exists (
 Select 1 
 From tableB b, tableC, tableD
 Where tableB.id = tableA.id
 And tableB.id_dtm = tableA.id_dtm
 And tableB.id = tableC.id
 And tableC.id = tableD.id)
```

Comment: The right answer, but he specifically asks if he can do this without using the tableA alias.

Comment: I wasnt aware that i could use the table name so this should work because the table name will always be the same. Thanks!

Comment: @EricPetroelje: This doesn't use an alias - it uses the actual table name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact setup but why can't you set an alias on the outer table? It doesn't have to reflect the actual table used, just alias it with "outer" or something. The use that in the inner query, you already know that id exists in whatever table is used outside so outer.id would work fine.

Answer (score -1):

The fields in the subquery which refer to `tableA` (i.e. `id` and `id_dtm`) also exist in the other tables, and so they are ambiguous. Solve this by prefixing those with the alias given to `tableA`:

```
Select A.id, A.id_dtm
From tableA A 
Where exists (
 Select 1 
 From tableB b, tableC c, tableD d
 Where b.id = A.id
 And b.id_dtm = A.id_dtm
 And b.id = c.id
 And c.id = d.id);
```

Comment: add description plz